# RxJS AJAX detect request is done from progressSubscriber ( whether success or error )

Tags: ajax, ecmascript-6, xmlhttprequest, rxjs, reactivex

I am really new to RxJS and I have a question regarding RxJS ajax request. I need to implement `progressSubscriber` to the `AjaxRequest` of RxJS ( because I need progress bar displayed from 0% to 100% ). However, from the code I made, I am not really sure how to detect when the request is **done**, then we can make some action when it happens.

After doing some inspection of my browser `console.log()`, I guess we can detect the **done** state from`progressSubscriber` response whether it has `status` property or not. Because from what I see, while it is in progress of making XHR request, it has no `status` property.

Is there any better way to detect a request is considered as **done** ( whether it is **success** or **error** ).

Currently here is my progress of getting **done** status ( in ES6 ):

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { ajax as rxAjax } from 'rxjs/ajax';
import { merge } from 'rxjs/operators';

let form_data = new FormData();
form_data.append( 'key', 'value' );

const progressSubscriber = new Subject();
let request$ = rxAjax({
  url: 'http://localhost.com/some-api',
  method: 'POST',
  crossDomain: true,
  withCredentials: true,
  body: form_data,
  progressSubscriber
});

progressSubscriber
  .pipe( merge(request$) )
  .subscribe( data =>{

    if ( data.hasOwnProperty('status') ) {
      console.log('XHR is DONE');
    }

  });
```

I hope there are more elegant ways of doing this. Maybe something that has 2 blocks of callbacks like **promise** `then()`, or `success & error` callback just like jQuery Ajax.

Thanks in advance.

**==========UPDATE/PROGRESS=============**

Based on the answer by [Fan Cheung](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8618350/fan-cheung), I've got inspired and searching for RxJS *error & complete signature*. Looks like I've learned in the past just forgot the basic of `subscribe()` which has the signature:

- function to call when `next()` occurred
- function to call when an error occurred
- function to call when done/complete

So, current progress I end up with following `subscribe()` ( based on above code ):

```
progressSubscriber
  .pipe( merge(request$) )
  .subscribe(
    data =>{
      if ( data.type === 'progress' ) {//Detect if it is response of Progress ( not XHR complete response )
        let upload_progress = Math.floor(data.loaded / data.total * 100 );
      }

      if ( data.hasOwnProperty('status') ) {
         //This is still the only way i can detect the request get complete
      }

    },

    err => {
      console.log( err.target.status ); //Just found that in RxJS, XHR server response is tied into `target` field
    },

    complete => {
      console.log( complete );//Complete will just give "undefined", seem we must really detect from first callback of subscribe() by detect if it has `status field from it response
    })
```

Anyone have a better idea, please advice. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `isLoading` property to track, tap operator to `switch` isLoading state

```js
merge(progressSubscriber.pipe(tap(()=>
this.upload_progress = Math.floor(data.loaded / data.total * 100 )
),
request$.pipe(tap(res)=>{},catchError((e)=>{..})
).subscribe()
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, however, I like to listen to `progressSubscriber` too. So, I can have a progress bar along with XHR upload progress. How I can listen to it by using your solution?

Comment: Actually, it is not just a simple `isLoading` true, but I really need a progress bar which from 0% to 100%. So I must really use `progressSubscriber`

Comment: in that case you can structure your code like the updated answer, then there's no need for if ...